# In AlpineJS, entangled array updates entire array instead of specific index

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working on dynamic sheet component using AlpineJS, and I am having a small problem.

```
<div x-data="dynamicSheetComponent({
                rows: @entangle($modelName),
                modelName: '{{ $modelName }}',
                columns: @js($columns),
                title: '{{ $title }}',
                selectedRows: [],
                cursorIndex: 0,
            })"
```

As you can see, I entangle the rows with a given modelName (retrieved using `$attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first()`)

Now, when a cell value changes, it fires a cell-value-change-intent event, and the component attempts to update the row like this:

```
cellValueChanged($event) {
            let row = $event.detail.row;
            let column = this.columns.find(column => column.key === $event.detail.columnKey);

            ....

            this.rows[$event.detail.rowIndex][column.key] = $event.detail.value;
}
```

This code works and keep the rows in sync between alpinejs and livewire without a problem, but it has an undesired behavior. Whenever I update a row, the entire entangled array is sent for update.

This is the relevant part of the livewire request payload:

```
"updates":[{"type":"callMethod","payload":{"id":"ccd7","method":"$set","params":["interveningClients",[{"name":"","nif":"","participation_percent":"55"}]]}}]}
```

As you can see, the entire array is being set again. I expected that, by changing only an index, I would get a payload like this:

```
"updates":[{"type":"callMethod","payload":{"id":"ccd7","method":"$set","params":["interveningClients.0.participation_percent",[55]]}}]}
```

Now, in most instances this would be acceptable, but in my current scenario, I need to know which $index was updated, and this is causing that in the following Livewire method :

```
updatedInterveningClients($value, $index)
```

$index is null (as expected from the payload I showed before).

So, I was wondering if there is a way to make entangled values to update only the index being modified.

Comment: for now, as a workaround, I changed this: this.rows[$event.detail.rowIndex][column.key] = $event.detail.value;  to this: this.$wire.set(this.modelName + "." + $event.detail.rowIndex + "." + $event.detail.columnKey, $event.detail.value);

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround